# Can you access forms in Outlook AppointmentItem in C#?

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I am accessing an Outlook calendar using c# and office.interOp.

Within Outlook Calendar, the Outlook developer tools allow you to add forms to appointments. This capability is used extensively within my organisation.

Is there a way to access these form fields from inside c# using the AppointmentItem object? If so, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you want to access any field on the object (including user defined fields):

```
    private object GetPropertyValue(AppointmentItem item, string propertyName)
    {
        ItemProperty property = item.ItemProperties[propertyName];
        return property.Value;
    }
```

If you want to access to other form fields (Name, category, sub categories, etc...)

```
     AppointmentItem item = (AppointmentItem)Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).Items.GetFirst();
     string category = item.FormDescription.Category;
     string subCategory = item.FormDescription.CategorySub;
     //...
```

Hope that helps